# Given independent random variables $X_{k}\sim\text{Poisson}(\lambda_{k})$, what is the distribution of $X_{1} + X_{2} + \ldots + X_{n}$?

Tags: probability, proof-verification, poisson-distribution, moment-generating-functions

Show that, if $X_{k}\sim\text{Poisson}(\lambda_{k})$ and they are independent for $1 \leq k \leq n$, then
\begin{align*}
Y = \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_{k}\sim\text{Poisson}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}\lambda_{k}\right)
\end{align*}

**MY SOLUTION**

To begin with, I am going determine the moment generating function of $X\sim\text{Poisson}(\lambda)$:
\begin{align*}
M_{X}(t) = \textbf{E}[e^{tX}] = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}e^{tk}e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^{k}}{k!} = e^{-\lambda}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(\lambda e^{t})^{k}}{k!} = e^{-\lambda}e^{\lambda e^{t}} = \exp(-\lambda(1 - e^{t}))
\end{align*}

Once these random variables are independent, the moment generating function of its sum is given by the product of each moment generating function:
\begin{align*}
M_{Y}(t) = \prod_{k=1}^{n}\exp(-\lambda_{k}(1-e^{t})) = \exp\left(-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\lambda_{k}(1-e^{t})\right)
\end{align*}

which means that $\displaystyle Y\sim\text{Poisson}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}\lambda_{k}\right)$, because random variables that have the same generating function have the same distribution.

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: Can't see anything wrong with this. Is there anything in particular that you are not sure about?

Comment: I am particularly interested in other solutions not involving moment generating functions. I know that the convolution theorem may be applied, but are there other approaches?

Comment: Besides MGF's (and by extension, characteristic functions) and convolutions, there really isn't any other elementary, slick way to prove this.

Comment: Another method would be to use induction and  convolutions. This is equally easy in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, guys :)